# How to implement the pattern apple uses for its Swift types like Array, Dictionary, and String

Tags: struct, swift, containers

So say I have a custom container class that I want to make pass by copy, but I don't want to copy it every time it is passed to a function.  So I want to copy the pattern Apple has used to create their `String`, `Array`, and `Dictionary` structs.  How could I create a container struct that only makes a copy whenever you use a setter on a copy of the struct.  The class implements `NSCopying` making it very easy to copy when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Swift uses copy-on-write for structures. What this means is that it behaves as if it were copying each time a pass-by-value occurs. However, a copy is only made when the object being copied is mutated.

In order to make your own type that makes use of this behaviour, create it as a `struct`. You will find that you have to make any function that mutates the structs state as a `mutating func`.

Comment: +1 Also, anything the docs list as a "value type" has this behavior. Beyond structs like array, dictionary, and string, that includes enums like Optional and Character.